# Is there a way to determine what application wants Java installed?

Tags: install, macos, java

After upgrading to Mountian Lion on both my MacBook Air and my wife's MacBook Pro, I recieved a prompt asking to install Java (I did not get this on my iMac).

I was wondering what triggered this event for it to ask for Java. Was it because a Java runtime was there previously? I don't remember installing one (and not sure why my Air would ask, but not my iMac, many more things are installed on my iMac).

How can I find out what triggered this? Also, how can I remove a runtime if an older, and now incompatible one was there?

Is there also a place where an older JVM may have been, and where it saw it there and decided to prompt me? If so, that would help me track down the notice, but also remove it from my machine.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this question. One of our macs keeps getting the Java prompt, and I'd like to know what application is responsible before (reluctantly) accepting the installation.

Comment: Related, this terminal command will look for applications that have a java component. I'm using it to decide whether to uninstall Java: `find /Applications -type f -name *.jar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some more research and finally found some things out:

- I have the Logitech remote software installed, and when launching it, it brings up the prompt, but a slightly different one. So, I know I have a few Java apps installed, but this was happening without me launching something
- My actual error was related to a Facebook chat thing I had installed a while back, that I never put on my iMac. It was named 'com.facebook.videochat.[username].plist', and was in my ~/Library/LaunchAgents directory.
- I actually came across [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61268/what-is-trying-to-launch-java-on-my-mac-os-x-mountain-lion) (asked after mine) when searching for the only Java information I found Console.app:

  > 8/31/12 6:44:23.606 PM Download Java Components[7588]:
  >   com.apple.message.domain:
  >   com.apple.java.usage2.DownloadOnDemand.complete
  >   com.apple.message.result: failure com.apple.message.signature:
  >   install_canceled com.apple.message.domain.version: 12A269
- I would recommend checking your ~/Library/LaunchAgents directory first, and you can easily grep for java by doing: `cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents` and then `grep -i "java" *.*`. This searches for the word java (case insensitive) in all files in that directory. Thats where I found the reference to the Facebook videochat plist.

Answer (score 0):

I resisted installing Java based on the prompt at startup, so I could see whether I would get a similar prompt when opening a specific application. For me the actual event went by quickly while I was caught up in work, but it seems to have been triggered by Adobe CS5 InDesign (or some associated application used by CS5).

Comment: I don't think I actually have any Adobe products installed.