# How to avoid Mountain Lion to asking for an Java installation?

Tags: macos, java

I uninstalled java today by using [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/78905/128).

Since then I get an dialog which asks me for installing java. This happens every time after a login to my user.
How can stop this request or how I can determine why I get this requests?

[image]

Comment: This is the same request that you get after a clean install of Mountain Lion that is free of Java. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/62683/128). I had this `com.facebook.videochat.[username].plist` file in my `~/Library/LaunchAgenst` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Check your login items (**System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Items**). If it's happening on every login, it's likely you have some process that requires Java in your login items.

Comment: also see [Is there a way to determine what application wants Java installed?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57898/is-there-a-way-to-determine-what-application-wants-java-installed)

Comment: My Login Items list contains only applications which are not needed Java!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find an explanation [amongst login items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/86739/8546) then you could begin with a log in as a different user, and command:

`sudo execsnoop -v`

Then log in as the user with the Java puzzle and note the time of appearance of the dialogue.

Switch to the first user, <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the run of `execsnoop` then consider the time range before the dialogue appeared.